# Can I use Enums when I declare the element number of an array?

Tags: c#

I am using the following in my code during the creation of a menu. The variables track the 
current top and sub menu titles:

```
        var topTitle = "";
        var subTitle = "";
```

Can I replace these with an array that uses the following Enum?

```
public enum MenuType {
    TopMenu = 0,
    SubMenu = 1
}
```

I assume I want an array of strings with two entries but how can I set this up and then reference
the array contents using my enum?

Comment: Sure you can... but _why_ do you want to? How do you intend to use it? It sounds to me like you should just define a class with those properties and assign your strings to them.

Comment: I was just thinking it would be good to have things done and also make use of the Enum. Something like Title[TopMenu] and Title[SubMenu]. Maybe the only thing I am a bit confused on is do I have to declare the array dimensions before I can use it?

Comment: Consider using Dictionary<MenuType,string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined a test class `MenuTest`, which uses [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and [this indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx):

```
public class MenuTest
{
    Dictionary<MenuType, string> myarray;

    public MenuTest()
    {
        myarray = new Dictionary<MenuType, string>();
    }

    public string this[MenuType index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (myarray.ContainsKey(index))
                return myarray[index];
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            myarray[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use it then:

```
MenuTest t = new MenuTest();
t[MenuType.TopMenu] = "topmenu";
t[MenuType.SubMenu] = "submenu";
Console.WriteLine(t[MenuType.TopMenu]);
Console.WriteLine(t[MenuType.SubMenu]);
```

Or you could use an extensions method for an array of strings to do the cast from enun to int:

```
public static string GetMenuByType(this string[] menu, MenuType type)
{
    int index = (int)type;
    if (menu.Length > index)
        return menu[index];
    else
        return null;
}
```

and use it:

```
 string[] menu = new string[] { "topmenu", "submenu" };
 Console.WriteLine(menu.GetMenuByType(MenuType.TopMenu));
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work with an enum, enum pairs a name with a int, its basically a fancy way of having a bunch of:

```
const int A = 0;
const int B = 1;
```

The advantage of an enum is you can place it in a method call, which then constrains usage of the method to only the const values you define in the enum. It also adds readability to code.

To achieve what you are looking for, you need a Dictionary collection.

You can then add your key pairs

```
Dictionary<String, String> titles = new Dictionary<String, String>();
titles.Add("topMenu", "Name of my top menu");
titles.Add("subMenu", "Name of my sub menu");
```

Then you can change values by:

```
titles["topMenu"] = "New name of my top menu";
titles["subMenu"] = "New name of my sub menu";
```

See if that will get you where you want to be. The types for key and value can be anything, this a very useful collection system.

Oh, and add to your usings:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum values are just integers. You can use them as you would use integers.

So doing this is correct:

```
public enum MenuType {
    TopMenu = 0,
    SubMenu = 1
}

string[] menuLabels = new string[]{"Name Top Menu", "Name Sub Menu"}:


menuLabels[MenuType.TopMenu] // A cast may be necessary here, not sure.
```

Of course, this is not the best way for using an enum, but it is as good as using a switch statement.